# Is there a way to disable the default containers on sagemaker studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

In sagemaker studio, there is a set of default images provided (e.g: datascience-2.0 for example). While this may be useful in most cases, there may be situations where we may need to disable it for enterprise related reasons. Is it possible?

Comment: I think there can be some workaround using IAM or a custom tool to monitor the running apps and if their name contains a specific name like the standard images -> kill them

Answer (score 0):

You can use IAM to control the images that a user can use to create apps on SageMaker Studio. A sample policy to prevent a user from launching unauthorized images is below -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "sagemaker:CreateApp"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotLike": {
          "sagemaker:ImageArns": [
            "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:image/{ImageName}"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the response. Do you know where can I get the exact name of the default containers in sagemaker studio in order to pass into the policy?